# Do two open diffeomorphic sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with the same boundary coincide?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  be open diffeomorphic subsets such that $\partial A=\partial B$.

Is it true that $A=B$?

(I have seen this claim somewhere but with no proof).

**Edit:**

As commented by Noah, this is not true in general: e.g take $A,B$ to be the left and right half-planes in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The question might be more interesting if we require $A,B$ to be bounded.

Comment: No, take the right half plane and the left half plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Maybe $A$ and $B$ should be bounded?

Comment: It's not true even for bounded open set: if you take a spiral ([like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=spiral&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNrOaWjrfWAhVD7oMKHRESAKsQ_AUICigB&biw=1517&bih=735#imgrc=rQEz70O7ckyuGM:), but it slowly has limit in a ball $D$) Let $A$ be the white part and $B$ the black one. Then they are diffeomorphic with $\partial A = \partial B$).

Comment: How does boundedness help? One can embed $\Bbb R^n$ as a bounded subset of itself.

Comment: @JohnMa This is interesting. What do you mean by "slowly"? Is there a point limit or circle limit?

Comment: @AsafShachar: Yes I mean having a circle limit.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, you seem to be right. Boundedness can't save it either.

Comment: It's true for interiors of codimension 0 compact submanifolds with boundary. Maybe this was the context where you saw the claim. But you do not need a diffeomorphism for this.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes,this is more or less the context. Can you elaborate on why the claim holds in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemma. Suppose that $M_1, M_2$ are codimension $0$ compact topological submanifolds of $E^n$ which have common boundary $C$. Then $M_1=M_2$.

Proof. Let $f_i: M_i\to E^n$ be the inclusion maps. Consider a manifold $M$ obtained from $M_1\sqcup M_2$ by gluing the boundaries of these manifolds via  the homeomorphism 
$$h=f_2^{-1}\circ f_1|_{\partial M_1}.$$
Then $M$ is a closed topological $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary. It comes equipped with a continuous map $f: M\to E^n$ as well as inclusion maps $\iota_k: M_k\to M$, $k=1,2$. The maps $g_k=f\circ \iota_k, k=1, 2$ are topological embeddings. I will leave it to you to check that $M$ is oriented so that the map $\iota_1$ preserves the orientation and $\iota_2$ reverses the natural orientation on the manifolds $M_1, M_2$ respectively.

If there is a point $x\in E^n - C$ such that $f^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton then there is also a small open ball $B\subset M$ containing $x$ such that for every $y\in f(B)$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is a singleton. Hence, we conclude that the map $f: M\to E^n$ has nonzero degree, which is impossible since $E^n$ is contractible. Thus, the restrictions of $g_1, g_2$ to the interiors of $M_1, M_2$ have the same image. In other words, $M_1=M_2$, regarded as subsets of $E^n$.  qed

Edit. For the sake of completeness: There exists a countably infinite collection of bounded open contractible subsets of $E^2$ (all homeomorphic, of course), which all have the same boundary. This example (due to Takeo Wada) is called "[Lakes of Wada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada)" (the original example had 3 such subsets). This example was discussed numerous times at MSE.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to see why there exist such a ball $B$: Suppose such a ball does not exist around $x$,  then there exist $x_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$ such that $f(x_n)=f(\tilde x_n)$ where $x_n \neq \tilde x_n$. W.L.O.G $x_n \in M_1, \tilde x_n \in M_2$; $x_n \to x$, and by compactness of $M_2$ we can assume $\tilde x_n$ converges to some point $\tilde x \in M_2$.  Now $x$, by its definition, belongs to $\text{int} M_1$, so $x \neq \tilde x$. (Actually $\tilde x \in \text{int}M_2$). So, $f(x)=f(\tilde x)$ has two "sources", a contradiction. Is this the argument you thought about?

Comment: @AsafShachar: No, that's too complicated. The reason is that both $M_1, M_2$ are closed, so their complements are open.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Last question if you will: Do you think the claim is true for submanifolds of arbitrary ambient manifold (instead of $E^n$). Since you used the contractibility of $E^n$ in your argument, I am not sure it adapts.

Comment: @AsafShachar, no, that's clearly false, consider for instance hemispheres in $S^n$. You need the ambient manifold to have zero top-dimensional homology group, that will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Just to for completeness:

It's not true that $A=B$, and boundedness assumption cannot help, since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to a bounded subset of itself.

Comment: When you take an unbounded example and shrink it to a bounded one by applying a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^n$ to a bounded subset $S$, the resulting sets have more boundary points than just the images of the boundary points of the original sets. Consider, for example, the "left and right half-planes" in Noah Olander's comment. If you shrink $\mathbb R^2$ to a disk, these become the left and right half-disks, whose boundaries are not only the line between the two sets but also different semicircles.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Then perhaps boundedness does ensure the sets coincide? I wonder now...

Comment: @AsafShachar: No, bounded is not enough. The standard 2-dimensional example is the "Lakes of Wada". Actually, you can have as many as you want (at most countably many, of course), all diffeomorphic to $R^2$, all sharing common boundary.